# Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined when using import path from 'path'

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

When using :

```js
import path from 'path';

path.resolve('/')
```

I get the title error, but when I use

```js
require('path').resolve('messages.json'))
```

[image]

```js
import { readFile, writeFile } from 'fs/promises';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
import path from 'path';

interface MessagesJson {
  messages: Array<{ content: string; id: string }>;
}

export class MessagesRepository {
  async findOne(id: string): Promise<string> {
    return id;
  }

  async findAll(): Promise<any> {
    return null;
  }

  async create(message: any): Promise<any> {
    console.log(' dirname', require('path').resolve('messages.json'));
    console.log(' path.resolve', path.resolve('/'));
    // console.log(' path.resolve', path.resolve(__dirname, '/src'));
    const messages: any = await readFile('src/messages.json', 'utf-8');

    const parsedMessages: MessagesJson = JSON.parse(messages);

    const newMessage = {
      content: message,
      id: uuidv4(),
    };

    await parsedMessages.messages.push(newMessage);

    await writeFile('src/messages.json', JSON.stringify(parsedMessages));

    return parsedMessages;
  }
}
```

For the problem context, I'm working on a small project with nestjs, any option for path.foo() gets the same error as listed above, is it something related for after the compiling of the code?

Im very lost to where/what doc and/or information should i be reading to be able to understand what is happening.

Comment: `import * as path from 'path';`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`require` on it's own is, by technicality, a named import. This means that in Typescript it needs to be like `import * as path from 'path'` so that you can make use  of `path.resolve`. Another option would be to deconstruct the import by using `import { resolve } from 'path';` and now you can just call `resolve()` directly.

Comment: This was a very silly mistake on my part, thank you very much for the answer!

Answer (score 3):

You can change your tsconfig.json.

like:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
   "esModuleInterop": true,
   ...
  },
  ...
}
```

After doing that, you don't need to use `* as xx` anymore.

More information: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#esModuleInterop